# How to open all the ports on Virtual Machine (classic) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to open all the ports, well actually from 1024 to 65535, on a classic virtual machine. But the endpoints are way too limited to do that. I read there were a maximum of 150 endpoints per machine. I tried to add a Network security group, but it just sits on top of the endpoints so it does not change anything, or is there a way to deactivate the endpoints, and only use Network security group? 
Or the only way is to switch to a "not classic" virtual machine?

Comment: This is a limitation of "classic" virtual machine deployments. There's really no need to deploy that way anymore. Is there a reason you can't use a Resource Manger based VM?

Comment: I was just willing to spare me the time to do the operation of migrating to a new VM :)

Comment: As the answer below state, you should migrate to ARM. That being said, you can migrate using the portal and it only takes a few mins :)

Comment: Oh really? So it does not break my current setup and data? I imagine there's a downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd need to migrate to ARM to achieve this.

Comment: Alright I did the migration that worked without any downtime gladly and now it works like I wanted :)